# Retrieve resized image from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage

I have a large image stored in firebase storage. Is there a way to get a resized version of that image to display? Current image takes a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this article https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556#.6fm2ua6dh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to do this:

- Compress images client side and upload smaller photos
- Use a Google Cloud Function or Google App Engine to resize/compress the photos after upload
- Use the Google App Engine Images API to generate serving URLs that you can then resize on the fly by requesting different (as mentioned in the blog post in the comment)
- Integrate with Imgix/Cloudinary to generate serving URLs with the above properties

Comment: Is that mean we have to keep generated serving URLs in firebase real-time db instead of firebase storage url ?

Comment: ok, we don't have to.  i found your answer in another question